# ios - Lower app's resolution

Tags: ios

I'm developing a game with a cocos2d. It was using Default.png images to identify resolutions. Now I switched my launch screen's to .xib file. Now my app run's at native resolution on all devices. But on iPhone 6 and 6 Plus I expect some perfomance issues, so I'm looking for ways to lower app resolution but still use .xib launch screen.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Once you setup a launch screen, your app will run at full device resolution for all possible devices. You can't provide a launch screen and have your app run at "iPhone 5" size on iPhone 6 devices, for example.

Your only option is to stick with launch images and have no launch screen.

<s>Of course if you need to support full sized iPad Pro support, that requires the use of a launch screen.</s> (Not true any more as of Xcode 8).